# Difference between multiple Slack sub packages in Airflow.providers.slack

Tags: airflow

I am new to Airflow and trying to post messages to a slack channel and I could see there are different sub packages in Airflow.providers.slack. I am confused about how the below are different from each other and what is the subpackage we should be using?

My confusion started when I saw slack_webhook availble in Hooks,notifications as well as operators. What is the difference? Please help me understand the same.

```
airflow.providers.slack.hooks
airflow.providers.slack.hooks.slack
airflow.providers.slack.hooks.slack_webhook

airflow.providers.slack.notifications
airflow.providers.slack.notifications.slack
airflow.providers.slack.notifications.slack_notifier
airflow.providers.slack.notifications.slack_webhook

airflow.providers.slack.operators
airflow.providers.slack.operators.slack
airflow.providers.slack.operators.slack_webhook

airflow.providers.slack.transfers
airflow.providers.slack.transfers.base_sql_to_slack
airflow.providers.slack.transfers.sql_to_slack
airflow.providers.slack.transfers.sql_to_slack_webhook
airflow.providers.slack.utils
```

Thanks,
Ajay Sakalabhaktula

I tried to understand the difference by opening the source code but did not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hooks](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/connections.html#hooks) is "high level" objects for communicate with Slack API or Slack Incoming WebHook, basically it provide wrapper around Slack SDK Client in addition it also provide Airflow connections for Slack.

[Operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/fundamentals.html#operators) for create Task in DAGs.

Transfers are specific Operators for communicate between different components, for Slack integration at that moment you might send query result (as text or file) into the Slack channel(s).

Notifications for send notification thought callbacks.

You might also check [Slack Provider documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-slack/stable/index.html), it also contain examples for Operators and Notifications